# Receive multidimensional text box array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have text box values to be posted . How do I take it in a PHP array .The html is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="ItemName[1][2]" >
<input type="text" name="ItemName[1][3]" >
<input type="text" name="ItemName[1][4]" >

$ItemNamesArray = $_POST[] ..... ????? What do I do in this step???
```

Please help.

Comment: Write print_r($_POST); in your code to see what you have to work with.

Comment: Webbandit: Excuse me, what? I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `var_dump($_POST)`, you'd see the answer right away:

```
array(1) {
  ["ItemName"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [2]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "b"
      [4]=>
      string(1) "c"
    }
  }
}
```

So you access `$_POST['ItemName'][1][2]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['ItemName'][1][2];
$_POST['ItemName'][1][3];
$_POST['ItemName'][1][4];
```

Comment: i want to access the ItemName[1] separately and ItemName[2] separately?

Comment: If you want to access `$ItemName[1]` or `$ItemName[2]` directly, instead of `$_POST['ItemName'][1]` or `$_POST['ItemName'][2]`, you can use `extract($_POST)`, and this way you will be able to access all the `$_POST` variables directly (i.e. `$ItemName[1]` instead of `$_POST['ItemName'][1]`). :)

Answer (score 0):

The post array can be accessed like 
    $ItemNamesArray = $_POST['ItemName']

and you can access the first item `$ItemNamesArray[1][2]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your example:

```
<input type="text" name="ItemName[1][2]" >
<input type="text" name="ItemName[1][3]" >
<input type="text" name="ItemName[1][4]" >
```

The `$_POST` key is going to be the name, so `ItemName` and because PHP treats the follow-up brackets as array keys, the values would be:

```
$_POST['ItemName'][1][2]
$_POST['ItemName'][1][3]
$_POST['ItemName'][1][4]
```

So if you want all item names, go with:

```
$itemNames = $_POST['ItemName'];
```

FYI,

1. you should sanitize and validate all input before using it.
2. If you don't actually have an `ItemName[2][1]` or `ItemName[0][1]` etc, then the following would make more sense:

   ```
    <input type="text" name="ItemName[]" />
    <input type="text" name="ItemName[]" />
    <input type="text" name="ItemName[]" />
   ```

Which would just set the index as they came in, instead of pre-setting them.